# Twitter Typeahead remote not completing some queries

Tags: typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am using Twitter Typeahead in version 0.11.1. Now I am trying to get remote working correctly, but somehow I think I am getting strange behavior.

This is the working code with a local array:

```js
var localArray = [{"value":"test0"},{"value":"test1"},{"value":"test2"},{"value":"test3"},{"value":"test4"}];
var myds = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: localArray
});
$(function () {
    $("#my-input").typeahead({},
    {
        name: 'ds1',
        source: myds,
        display: 'value'
    });
});
```

Now I try to setup remote data. What I did is just to change local to remote and provide the URL and add a query parameter. It will deliver exactly the same structure and data as localArray (it currently ignores the query and always delivers the content of localArray just to test this). I checked in Chrome Developer Tools that the query is actually executed and returns the content of localArray:

```js
var myds = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/autocomplete?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }    
});
$(function () {
    $("#my-input").typeahead({},
    {
        name: 'ds1',
        source: myds,
        display: 'value'
    });
});
```

Somehow this does not work when searching for `test`. When searching for `tes` I still get results, but when I search for `test`, no result is offered for autocompletion. There are other words for which this does not work, and it seems to follow the same schema, like a complete word is not found while parts of words are found. Any idea what causes this behavior or how to fix it?

My guess is that the remote datasource has to be in another format, but I cannot find how it has to look. All the examples on the typeahead page look very similar...

Comment: What format is your remote data in?

Comment: It is plain json: ``[{"value":"test0"},{"value":"test1"},{"value":"test2"},{"value":"test3"},{"value":"test4"}]``

Comment: I want to see if you are experiencing a known bug with typeahead. Could you add a `limit: 2` to your typeahead settings and see if the other searches start working (of course only returning 2 results)?

Comment: Added the limit, but the behavior stays the same :( I tried adding it to the Bloodhound engine, then removed it there, added it to the typeahead settings, then both, but seems not to make a difference

Comment: Okay, I thought you might be experiencing the issue outlined here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1232 , but I guess not. That's strange, it looks like you have an identical setup to my own typeahead usage and everything looks fine. Unfortunately the main typeahead repo is no longer maintained. Even though it doesn't look like your problem, you might want to consider either making this change yourself or using a PR that does. It is a pretty annoying bug. https://github.com/coopy/typeahead.js/commit/387290b1e70be0052c6dd9be84069f55d54a7ce7

Comment: Note that if you make that change manually (like I did) you just need to move down the `rendered += suggestions.length;` line. Don't worry about the spec file, that's just a test.

Comment: Moving down the rendered line seems to fix the problem, I will test this a little and give you feedback about it in a few minutes

Comment: Okay, that line also caused weird results for me. If this fixes your problem please do let me know and I'll make it an answer so that others can see.

Comment: Ok, so I tested with the rest of my code and now everything works as expected. Thank you very much, I really appreciate the help! Please post your comment suggesting that line as an answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing a [bug](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1232) in typeahead. It causes strange behavior when dealing with result sets that are the same as, or less than, the limit declared in typeahead (default limit is 5). Unfortunately the main typeahead repo is no longer maintained so you will either have to use a PR that fixes the issue or edit the code yourself. Luckily, the fix is just moving down one line of code.

Either in the compiled bundle or in `src/typeahead/dataset.js` find this block of code and change it to:

```
function async(suggestions) {
    suggestions = suggestions || [];
    if (!canceled && rendered < that.limit) {
        that.cancel = $.noop;
        that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
        rendered += suggestions.length;
        that.async && that.trigger("asyncReceived", query);
    }
}
```

All this does is move `rendered += suggestions.length;` *below* `that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));`;

This is exemplified in [this PR](https://github.com/coopy/typeahead.js/commit/387290b1e70be0052c6dd9be84069f55d54a7ce7).